# How to select first row only in 2nd table of inner join query

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using the following query to select data from 3 different tables. tbl_invoices and tbl_clients have unique records. Each tbl_invoices record has multiple tbl_invoice_entries records:

```
$query = 'SELECT T1.*, T2.*, T3.* 
                FROM tbl_invoices T1 
                LEFT JOIN tbl_invoice_entries T2
                ON T1.number = T2.invoice_number
                LEFT JOIN tbl_clients T3
                ON T1.client = T3.client_id
                WHERE date_format(date, '%Y') = ".$_POST['year']." AND date_format(date, '%c') = ".$_POST['month']." ORDER BY date, number ASC'

$stmt = $conn->prepare($query)
$stmt->execute();    
$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

This currently returns all records in tbl_invoice_entries. How do I change my query in order to only return the first tbl_invoice_entries record for each tbl_invoices record.

Here are the tables:

tbl_clients

```
+----+-----------+----------+
| id | firstname | lastname |
+----+-----------+----------+
|  1 | John      | Doe      |
|  2 | Jane      | Doe      |
+----+-----------+----------+
```

tbl_invoices

```
+----+--------+--------+------------+
| id | number | client |    date    |
+----+--------+--------+------------+
|  1 |     14 |      1 | 2015-07-14 |
|  1 |     15 |      2 | 2015-07-14 |
+----+--------+--------+------------+
```

tbl_invoice_entries

```
+----+----------------+------------+
| id | invoice_number |  produkt   |
+----+----------------+------------+
|  1 |             14 | Fish       |
|  2 |             14 | Bread      |
|  3 |             15 | Vegetables |
|  4 |             15 | Fruit      |
+----+----------------+------------+
```

So the results I'm looking for are:

John Doe 14 Fish 2015-07-14

Jane Doe 15 Vegetables 2015-07-14

Thanks for any help!

Comment: may b it's not the query just the way you are fetching it, post your code where you are fetching the data.

Comment: please put table structure. http://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/ will help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell the RDBMS what you intend by *the first row*. There is no natural order in tuples. If you want the *tuple with lowest ID given the same invoice_number*, then it would require another query

```
SELECT tbl1.* FROM tbl_invoice_entries AS tbl1
    JOIN ( SELECT MIN(id) AS id, invoice_number FROM tbl_invoice_entries
         GROUP BY invoice_number ) AS tbl2
    USING (id);
```

The above query is equivalent to `tbl_invoice_entries` but only has the lowest ID of each invoice number. You can do it as a VIEW (actually two, since you can't use subqueries in a VIEW):

```
CREATE VIEW tbl_invoice_entries_firstnumber AS
  SELECT MIN(id) AS id, invoice_number
  FROM tbl_invoice_entries
  GROUP BY invoice_number;

CREATE VIEW tbl_invoice_entries_first AS
  SELECT tbl1.* FROM tbl_invoice_entries AS tbl1
  JOIN tbl_invoice_entries_firstnumber
  USING (id);
```

After that you can use `tbl_invoice_entries_first` instead of `tbl_invoice_entries` in your current query.

Keep in mind that the view is *dynamic*, so it is only a shorthand for a more complex query. This means that your current query will become more complicated and require a longer time:

```
SELECT T1.*, T2.*, T3.* 
    FROM tbl_invoices AS T1 
    LEFT JOIN tbl_invoice_entries_first AS T2
        ON T1.number = T2.invoice_number
    LEFT JOIN tbl_clients AS T3
        ON T1.client = T3.id; -- you have no client_id in T3
```

I have set up a fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3a419/3/0).

Or you can modify your query more, and add a JOIN condition on T2 so that it only fetches, again, the minimum ID - or whatever ordering condition you prefer:

```
SELECT T1.*, T2.*, T3.* 
    FROM tbl_invoices AS T1 
    LEFT JOIN tbl_invoice_entries AS T2
        ON (
          -- (( T1.number = T2.invoice_number AND  )) --
          T2.id = (
          SELECT MIN(id) FROM tbl_invoice_entries 
          WHERE invoice_number = number
        ))
    LEFT JOIN tbl_clients AS T3
        ON T1.client = T3.id;
```

**UPDATE**: *The check on number was commented out (see also @cars10's solution) because it is carried over by the inner subquery.*

Finally you can do this in code, i.e. you save the value of the previous tuple and order the query as needed; then discard all unneeded tuples. If you have few entries per invoice, this might be worthwhile:

```
 // pseudo code

 if (prev.client == tuple.client)
    and
    (prev.invoice == tuple.invoice)
        continue;
 prev = tuple;
 -- use tuple.
```

Comment: @Iserni: cool, thanks. Nice clear explanation. Went for the JOIN condition solution.

Comment: I see now that I left over the join on invoice number, which the inner MIN makes redundant. You may want to accept the solution by @cars10 (once "optimized", my solution is the same as his, and he got it first).

Answer (score 2):

By linking the invoice_entries table not directly through the invoice number but by the id of its first entry you can achieve what you want:

```
SELECT firstname,lastname,number,product,date
 FROM tbl_invoices T1 
 LEFT JOIN tbl_invoice_entries T2
 ON T2.id =(select min(id) from tbl_invoice_entries 
            where invoice_number=number)
 LEFT JOIN tbl_clients T3
 ON T1.client = T3.id
 WHERE ...
```

Comment: Good call, but note that the OP inadvertently entered *T3.client_id* when it should have been (given his structure) *T3.id*.

Comment: Yes, thanks for mentioning it! And there was another typo - corrected it now. Can't test properly as I am writing this on my iPod. ;-)